# How can I get Stack Overflow datasets related to comment ending with .csv?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I am working on my thesis and I need to get Stack Overflow datasets related to the "comments" ending with ".csv".

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps

Comment: I think very few comments on StackOverflow end with ‘.csv’.

Comment: @user3840170 precisely 832 as of today

Comment: Why are comments ending with ".csv" interesting?

Comment: What are some examples of such comments?

Comment: I would also like to know.csv

Comment: And that's another one.csv

Comment: Meanwhile, please allow me to get all SO comments and put them into a .csv.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to download the datadump and don't want to fiddle with T-SQL in SEDE you can download about 500,000 comments in one go [with this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1580983?limit=1000). The query makes use of the [PIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) statement to spread row values across multiple columns.

```sql
declare @limitrows int = ##limit?100000##

declare @cols int = 10 -- if you change this 
                       -- change the column labels as well
                       -- in two places !

select [row]
      -- 10 cols
      , [0]
      , [1]
      , [2]
      , [3]
      , [4]
      , [5]
      , [6]
      , [7]
      , [8]
      , [9]
from 
    (select (seq-1) % @cols [col]
    , row / @cols [row]
    , text
    from
    ( select top (@limitrows)
       row_number() over(order by id) seq
     , row_number() over(order by id) row
     , text
     from comments ) as c
     ) as ca
pivot (
   min(text)
     for ca.col in ( 
      -- 10 cols
        [0]
      , [1]
      , [2]
      , [3]
      , [4]
      , [5]
      , [6]
      , [7]
      , [8]
      , [9])
) p
```

You first run the query and after you got a result, click the *Download CSV* button at the top right of the result grid. I indicated that button with a red free hand circle in the below screenshot:

[image: Insane result grid, showing columns 1, 2, 3 and 4. The button download csv at the top right of the grid is encircled]

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to parameterize the inner query that drives which comments get selected. The answer from [Oleg Valter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417562)  can be helpful with that.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the excellent [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Christ, that's a clever way to get the comments for later processing :)

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to data dumps, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (aka SEDE). Although due to sheer [number of comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1580969) on Stack Overflow, such a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1580968) is going to be *slow* due to the leading wildcard, but can fit into the execution time limit if you forgo the ordering:

```tsql
select
  *
from
  comments
where
  text like '%' + ##Ending:string##
```

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange in general [runs data dumps](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/) that are available for public consumption (list of all dumps can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224873/244695)). In particular, SO (due to the site's size) breaks data dumps into separate dumps. [The March 17, 2022 dump of comments is here](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Comments.7z). You'll have to parse it for what you need, but it's the easiest way to compile the data you seek.

Good luck!